# Java: Override paintComponent to skip some paint = strange behavior

Tags: java, paintcomponent

I am not new to Java, but somewhat inexperienced using graphics.

I am using JFreeChart to display strip charts of data that comes in very fast (every 10 ms).  It works fine for a single chart, but I have multiple charts so my code cannot keep up with the server.  I decided to override the paintComponent method in my JPanel and skip painting some of the frames.  That did improve performance, but now there is strange behavior: I have 6 charts (each in a JPanel), and they do update as expected but 1 of the six charts flickers into the place of the other 5, then they all flicker back to themselves, then the 1 chart is in all 6, etc.  This happens very fast.  The chart that flickers in to all 5 is random every time I run this code, so maybe the others are also flickering in and out but I cannot see it.

```
@Override  
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
   if ((count++ % UPDATESKIP) == 0)
   {
      super.paintComponent(g);
   }
}
```

If UPDATESKIP = 1 then this code runs fine, but very slow.

Answer (score 1):

You should not play with the painting method in that way. All the paintComponent() method of a JPanel does is paint the background of the panel. So I doubt that is where the performance problem is.

Every time the panel is repainted the child components of the panel need to be repainted, so not repainting the background will have little impact (relative to the complexity of painting 6 charts). However, if you don't paint the background every time then you can get painting artifacts on the panel.

Take a look at the Swing tutorial on [A Closer Look at the Painting Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

If the server data comes in too fast then maybe you need to consolidate the data before redoing the painting

Answer (score 0):

I did more (better) searches and found the answer here:
[Enabling/Disabling drawing of a JFreeChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627976/enabling-disabling-drawing-of-a-jfreechart).
The answer by [Aleadam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542701/aleadam) was perfect and did the job for me.  I'd vote that answer up but I am too new to do so.